# passing variable using void *

Tags: c++, callback, void-pointers

I was writing an interface(using FLTK but this doesn't matter). I made a button and its callback function. In this callback function I need to use data in a variable outside the callback function(which is Myclass mc in the code). The code looks like the following (I didn't paste the unnecessary parts):

```
class Myclass
{
    ...
}

void button_callback( Fl_Widget* o, void* data) 
{
   Fl_Button* button=(Fl_Button*)o;
   Myclass *a;
   a=data;
   a->MyMemberFunction();
}

int main()
{
    Myclass mc;
    ...
    Fl_Button button( 10, 150, 70, 30, "A button" );
    button.callback( button_callback,&mc );
    ...
}
```

However at the place of "a=data;" I got an error saying void * cannot be assigned to Myclass *, what should I do?

Many thanks!

Comment: try `a = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(data);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the data coming in through the `void*` is a pointer to `Myclass`, you need to add a `reinterpret_cast` from the `void*`, like this:

```
Myclass *a = reinterpret_cast<Myclass*>(data);
```

This will tell the compiler that you know for sure that the `data` is a pointer to `Myclass`, letting you call `MyMemberFunction()` through that pointer.

Comment: Re "you need", that's incorrect since a `static_cast` will do fine, and with more formal support, but I agree that a `reinterpret_cast` more directly conveys the conceptual operation and is preferable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I agree, `static_cast` would be the "weakest" of the casts to do the job here. As a rule, however, I use `reinterpret_cast` when casting from a `void*`, because conceptually "pointers to nothing" need to be reinterpreted to become something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use any kind of type casting:

here is C variant:

```
Myclass *a = (Myclass*)data;
```

here is C++ variant:

```
Myclass* a = reinterpret_cast<Myclass*>(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried both, the first one also works somehow though in a cpp file.